# Odoo v8 survey user invitation and number answer per user issue?

Tags: odoo, odoo-survey

I'm trying to use the new version of Odoo Survey and survey_crm but I'm facing the following problems.
[image: Quzz mode]

1. In the previous version there is an option of restricting number of answer per user but in this new version there is no such option (may be I don't know yet), however I tried the following:

   - Quizz mode (check box): I used this but still not working any user has an option to answer twice 
     [image: Test link]
   - In the invitation I used the last option (which is, Send private invitation to your audience(only one response per recipient and per invitation)) but still this option wouldn't prevent user answering more than once b/c of "Test" link  in the Kanban view of Survey
     [image: error]
2. when I tried to send any invitation it popups an error saying OpenERP server error even if I successfully configure my outgoing and incoming email server but when i try it again without and modification it sends with out any error.

Comment: Are you using developer version?

Comment: I found it in this link https://www.odoo.com/page/download

Answer (score 0):

As in v8 we are getting wizard.survey_id as "survey.survey" object , instead of id. so, override the _get_public_url function as below:

```
def _get_public_url(self, cr, uid, ids, name, arg, context=None):
    res = dict((id, 0) for id in ids)
    survey_obj = self.pool.get('survey.survey')
    for wizard in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if isinstance(wizard.survey_id,int):
            res[wizard.id] = survey_obj.browse(cr, uid, wizard.survey_id, context=context).public_url
        else:
            res[wizard.id] = wizard.survey_id.public_url
    return res
```

While Share and Invite by Mail select "Send private invitation to your audience (only one response per recipient and per invitation)" option so that it sends a unique link for each contact and you can able to see those linked Tokens in Answers.

One more thing, these links won't work until and unless the Odoo server start with db-filter option(if multiple databases are present). Because, with these links data base name is not present. So, if we click on these generated links it returns an Error like "This webpage is not available".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add information to your answer by *editing* it, instead of commenting. Do this by clicking "edit" underneath the post.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.